# How to mock Cosmos upsert

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to mock Cosmos upsert, this way:

```
jest.mock('@azure/cosmos', () => {
  return {
    CosmosClient: jest.fn(() => ({
      database: jest.fn(() => ({
        container: jest.fn(() => ({
          items: jest.fn(() => ({
            upsert: jest.fn(() => ({})),
          })),
        })),
      })),
    })),
  };
});
```

My code looks like this:

```
const { resource } = await this.container.items.upsert<Data>(data);
```

However, when I run the tests, Cosmos tries to connect to the endpoint; in other works, it is not being mocked.

I also tried

```
const upsertMock = jest.spyOn(Items.prototype, 'upsert');
```

But no luck too.

Comment: Generally, don't mock what you don't own. You can see how complex a test double you've had to create. Introduce a simple facade you can easily mock, and/or integration test.